# How to get four dimensional matrix using for loop

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

k is 3-D matrix. How do I get the 4-D from this

```
    a = 0:5:20;
    b = length(a);
    for i = 1:Nz
        c = K*z(i);  
    end
```

I don't know how to modify it accordingly. Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Dan. I did not understand what you are trying to say. May you help me out to modify the code so that I could achieve the objective.

Comment: No because I cannot understand your objective at all. Ignore my previous comment, I was mistaken.

Comment: @Dan, I am trying to get 4-D matrix of a, whereas upon implementing this, I am getting 3-D matrix. k is obtained only for z=20. I wan to save k for other z values also.

Comment: @Dan. sorry it is 4-Dimensional matrix of `a` not `k`. `k` is 3 dimensional matrix.

Comment: try `a=[]` before your loop and then in the loop do `a = cat(4,a,exp(1i*K*z(i));` Also, if you are working with complex number then you should probably not use `i` as a variable name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to concatenate on the 4th dimension:

```
a = [];
for slice = 1:Nz
    a = cat(4,a,exp(1i*K*z(slice)));  
end
```